# How to combine two 3dplot in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to draw a plot3d of Multivariate t distribution and also appear the correspond countourplot in the bottom of it. 
I use the following code

`Needs["MultivariateStatistics"]`

`A = Plot3D[
  PDF[MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}, 10], {x, 
    y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

`B = ContourPlot[
  PDF[MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}, 10], {x, 
    y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

`Show[A, B]`

but I could not. I knew if using the function `show` in the univariate case, the plots combined.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3665/121), and also consider asking your questions on [the new site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

`Show` "effectively overlays the graphics" on top of each other, so you probably want something like `Column` or `GraphicsColumn` to place them in a column:

```
GraphicsColumn[{A, B}, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> White]
```

[image: stacked]